# Removing 'using filesort' from query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, filesort

I have the following query:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      shop_user_member_spots
WHERE     delete_flag = 0
ORDER BY  date_spotted desc
LIMIT     10
```

When run, it takes a few minutes. The table is around 2.5 million rows.

Here is the table (not designed by me but I am able to make some changes):

[image: database table]

And finally, here are the indexes (again, not made by me!):
[image: indexes]

I've been attempting to get this query running fast for hours now, to no avail.

Here is the output of EXPLAIN:
[image: explain output]

Any help / articles are much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to alias the table in simple select

Comment: I don't, this query was part of a bigger query and I didn't remove the alias. I'll remove that now if it makes you happier :-)

Comment: Roughly how many rows (25? 2 million?) are likely to have deleted_flag set to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your query, it seems the index you would want would be on `(delete_flag, date_spotted)`.  You have an index that has the two columns, but the `id` column is in between them, which would make the index unhelpful in sorting based on `date_spotted`.  Now whether mysql will use the index based on Zohaib's answer I can't say (sorry, I work most often with SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see in the explain plan is that the index on spotted date is not being used, insted filesort mechanism is being used to sort (as far as index on delete flag is concerned, we actually gain performance benefit of index if the column on which index is being created contains unique values)

the mysql documentation says

Index will not used for order by clause if

> The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key2=constant ORDER BY key1;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
I guess same is the case here. Although you can try using Force Index

Comment: I saw that but wasn't sure what to do with that new knowledge. I've tried using force index but wasn't sure what index to use it on or what indexes to create.

Comment: I am not very sure, but according to the docs, index on (delete_flag, spotted date) might help.